# Next and previous document from elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Is there any way to get the next and previous document from elasticsearch based on an id and search options ?

I have documents stored in ES and I made an app to explore those documents.
You can choose from various filters which will build a search request returning a list of document (their order is very important !)
You can then select a document from the list and I would like to access the previous and next documents (order based on the search options)
I can't store the whole list as it may be made of more than 100k entries.

I have no control over the Elasticsearch structure, all I have access to is making search/byId requests

Comment: From, to (pagination) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size allow you to select results by packs.

Comment: @LeBigCat The pagination won't help me because it uses the index of the document in the search array instead of the actual _id of the document. I have to use the _id or I will be stuck with the rest of the app

Comment: Ok my bad, misunderstood. So to be clear : You have a query, this query return a document and you have to retrieve the doc+1 and doc-1 right?

Comment: @LeBigCat Actually I have a query (with pagination), the query return a part of the whole document list. I select a document (extract the document's id and forward it to another page), I query the document by Id and now I would like to get +1 -1 documents